# Can We use string resources for code comment in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, string.xml

Suppose we have some statement for comments which will be repeat many times. Can We use string resources for code comment in android?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have 3 files where i have to write 3 statements as comment i do not want to write same lines again and again so i thought there may be a solution  for it via string resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Comments are ignored by the compiler and runtime engine, therefore there would be no point in referring to a String resource. If you are looking to create the same comment over and over in the source code,  [recording a macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) in Android Studio will do the job better:

> Edit -> Macros -> Start Recording Macro

Type out your comment

> Edit -> Macros -> Stop Recording Macro

Give your macro a name. Then to use your macro again:

> Edit -> Macros -> Play saved macro...

You can also map your macro to a key combination via:

> File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Macros

Comment: Thanks @Michael for a quick response let me try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> Can We use string resources for code comment in android?

**No You can't**

Comments are just ignored by compiler and never get executed.

Comment: Thanks @V-rund Puro-hit